# How to debug if android.resource:// does exist when having Uri to that resource

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-resources

I am working on push notifications with `Android studio` with my phone plugged in via USB as debugging device and notifications are coming through just fine custom text set, etc. However when I try to set custom sound by using

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm);
```

which then evaluates to `android.resource://gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart/2131099648` it does not play ball.

My guess is that sound file is not there and it simply fails silently.

**Code:**

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm);
    // RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**How would I debug the application where by having Url I could confirm if resource is there or not?**

Comment: BTW, I am imbecile - I had sound off on my mobile :) Still question stands.